# How to retrieve image from SQL Server database in ASP.NET using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have some images in a SQL Server database and I want to retrieve those images in ASP.NET. But it gives me an error

> *The file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\DevServer\10.0\130065367816821657' already exists.*

Please solve my problem.

```
protected void DropDownList1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("select * from imageCollection where img_id='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'", cn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
        SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

        try
        {
            if (dr.Read())
            {

                string image1 = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
                string image2 = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
                FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(image1, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
                FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(image2, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
                byte[] bimage1 = (byte[])dr["passport_photo"];
                byte[] bimage2 = (byte[])dr["sign_photo"];
                fs1.Write(bimage1, 0, bimage1.Length - 1);
                fs2.Write(bimage2, 0, bimage2.Length - 1);
                fs1.Flush();
                fs2.Flush();
                Image1.ImageUrl = "~/images"+bimage1.ToString();
                Image2.ImageUrl = "~/images"+bimage2.ToString();
            }
            dr.Close();
            cn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

I have uploaded images from "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0" and the front end code is as of following:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string image1 = FileUpload1.FileName;
    string image2 = FileUpload2.FileName;
    FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(image1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(image2, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] bimage1 = new byte[fs1.Length];
    byte[] bimage2 = new byte[fs2.Length];
    fs1.Read(bimage1, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs1.Length));
    fs2.Read(bimage2, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs2.Length));
    fs1.Close();
    fs2.Close();
    cn.Open();
    SqlParameter sp = new SqlParameter();
    sp.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Image;
    sp.ParameterName = "@passport_photo";
    sp.ParameterName = "@sign_photo";
    sp.Value = bimage1;
    sp.Value = bimage2;
    SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO imageCollection values(@img_id," + "@passport_photo,"+"@sign_photo)", cn);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img_id",TextBox1.Text);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passport_photo",sp.Value=bimage1);
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sign_photo",sp.Value=bimage2);
    cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cm.Dispose();
    cn.Dispose();
    cn.Close();
}
```

}

Comment: `DateTime now = DateTime.Now;` before the first string and `now = DateTime.Now;` before the second might do too. Agustin's way is better though

Comment: You might also consider using `using` statements.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that `image1` and `image2` are equal.

```
string image1 = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
string image2 = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
```

Consider using something to differentiate both filenames:

```
string image1 = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime()) + "1";
string image2 = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime()) + "2";
```

As you can imagine, the code involved in create your filename `Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime())` executes really fast, so there is not time enough to let `DateTime.Now` increases its value.

**EDIT**

You may also change the directory where the images are written:

```
 FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/images/" + image1), FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
 FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/images/" + image2), FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
```

Otherwise, the files are written in the application folder (`bin`)

And then

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/images/" + image1;
Image2.ImageUrl = "~/images/" + image2;
```

Now have sense

Ensure that the ASP.NET user has write permissions in the "images" folder.

Comment: Hello,Now it's not showing error.But it doesn't displaying images in asp.net image control. Please find a solution. Thanks....

Comment: I tried your above written code. Now it's giving an error "Could not find a part of the path 'E:\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite7\images\1300654290703737531'."

Comment: Seems like the `image` folder isn't there. Have you verified that the folder exists?

Comment: yes.I have verified. it exists.

Comment: So, verify what part in the `E:\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite7\images\1300654290703737531` path string is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Also, your code is set to throw an error if a file with a duplicate filename is found:

```
FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(image1, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(image2, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
```

The following code will allow a file to be overwritten, by changing `FileMode.CreateNew` to `FileMode.Create`:

```
FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(image1, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(image2, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
```

Comment: Hello dear... I have tried your above written code and it's showing an error "Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\130064619000881758'."

Comment: This is to do with where the image is saved. It really is a different question.

Comment: I have saved my images in Sqlserver database in image format. I have uploaded images from front end.

Comment: If you open a new question about downloading an image, we can give you a fuller answer.